# Express.js SEO How to submit a page to a search engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a SPA application. And I need to do SEO for it, Next.js is too late to use. Therefore, the choice fell on express.js We have a back on Rest-api. Is there any quick way to set the paths for the pages as in the example and give it only to search engines, and show ordinary users everything that comes from react?

```
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

The bottom line is that I want to fill in the empty index.html meta tags and fill the site through different links through rest api requests and give it to search engine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using react. You can use `isbot` to detect search engine bots. for each page you render you can have `get` request and in each handler you can use templating engine to generate html for the page. you can use react components as placeholders and if request is from search engine bot you can render the html instead of the react app. hope this helps.

Comment: I don't get it. How bots will get my express.js and not my react app like ordinary users

Comment: you'll need a templating engine, once you have it your requests will look something like this: 
`app.get('/', function(req, res) {
//this will be generated by templating engine
  const templateVars = { pageTitle: 'About' };
  
  if (isSearchEngine(req.headers['user-agent'])) {
    const html = renderTemplate('' ", templateVars);
    res.send(html);
  } else {
    res.render('' ", templateVars);
  }
});

function isSearchEngine(userAgent) {
  // check if user is SE bot
}`